# ¿Programar un enter en java?

Tags: java

Hola compañeros mi duda es la siguiente: 
necesito que después de pulsar un opción del menú se haga un enter por defecto es decir no que yo presione la tecla si no que automáticamente se haga. ¿hay alguna manera de hacerlo en java? Gracias.

Comment: Hola Pedro, bienvenido a [es.so] te recomendamos que visites el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento del sitio y además conseguir tu primera medalla, por otro lado es igual de importante que visites [ask] para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas. Un saludo

Comment: Tal vez te sirva esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4420301/3239070

Comment: ¿Quieres el evento o que funcione como si un usuario lo hiciera?

Comment: Quiero que funcione como si un usuario lo hiciera

Comment: Tu opción de menú está hecha con Swing, AWT o alguna librería de gráficos en particular? Adicionalmente te recomiendo poner un [mcve]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Puedes usar la clase `Robot` de Java

Primero, importas las librerías necesarias:

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
```

Entonces:

> En este ejemplo `try` `catch` es para demostrar la forma de capturar las excepciones de esta clase por lo que su uso no es obligatorio

```
try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();

        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); // Simula presionar la tecla
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); // Simula soltar la tecla

} catch (AWTException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Error");
}
```

> **Actaulización:** No se como está programado tu menú, pero puedes crear un método que sea llamado desde el mismo.

Ejemplo:

```
public class TuClase
{
  private java.awt.Robot robot = null;

   public void PresionarEnter()
   {
       robot = new Robot();
       robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

       //O este, aun mas simple
       new java.awt.Robot().keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
   }
}
```

Entonces, solo debes llamar al método `PresionarEnter()` cuando se haga click en el elemento de tu menu

Aquí te dejo máas información: [how-to-use-robot-class-in-java](https://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips-100019/21-java-awt/1758-how-to-use-robot-class-in-java.html)

Comment: En tu respuesta no se asegura que se realice el enter cuando lo requiere, ya que no indicas como integrarlo con su código

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro Bueno, el OP no ha posteado código alguno, por lo que necesitaria primero verlo. Debido a que no hay código en la pregunta, le he dado una base se donde partir

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro En la pregunta, se habla de un menu, pero no se especifica que control uso ni que código. Si el OP muestra su código, mi pregunta puede ser editada para adaptarse al mismo

Comment: Entonces te recomiendo leer el artículo [Te podrían votar negativamente porque no esperaste a entender la pregunta antes de contestar.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3217/342), aunque en mi opinión personal podrías indicar el punto donde debe obtener el evento para que sepa el órden en que debe de poner su código, si antes o después

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro Muchas gracias, pero ya lo he leido, no dejes que mi baja reputacion (o mis 11 insigneas de bronze) en SO en español te engañe haciendote creer que soy un principiante, en SO tengo mucha mas, por lo que se como manejarme en el sitio

Comment: Entonces ya deberías de saber que no todas las preguntas deben de ser respondidas para mantener la calidad del sitio, ya que no cumplen con los requisitos mínimos para ser buenas preguntas

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro Preguntas como esta? [java-error-on-token-expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848296/java-error-on-token-expected/49848499#49848499)

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro, bueno, la respondi hace 24 horas, y es de baja calidad, pero a pesar de eso, mi respuesta no ha recibido votos negativos, al contrario, tiene un voto positivo, y fue marcada como aceptada. Porque? porque SO es un sitio para ayudar a la gente

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro Ademas, no veo voto negativo alguno en mi respuesta, pero si quieres puedes darle tu el voto negtivo, yo me conformo con que el OP sepa por donde partir

Comment: Yo lo aprendí hace unos meses con una pregunta de baja calidad( ojo que eso no quiere decir fácil ), deberías revisar la discusión en el meta https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2906/la-calidad-de-una-respuesta-depende-de-la-calidad-de-una-pregunta

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro Deberias saber que una respuesta no debe decir lo que alguien comento en la pregunta amigo, y eso que quieres ya lo comentó MLStud en la pregunta del OP ;-)

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro Despues de echarle un vistazo a la discusion (y de marcala como favorita) me doy cuenta que eres un cuidador, y por eso te inquieta mi respuesta

Sabes? SI lo hiciera por reputacion, tendria mas de 200. Yo no soy el unico que responde preguntas como esta ;-)

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro Y muchas gracias por el post en Meta, me servira para referencias futuras

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro Solo 3 de mis 99 respuestas han sido votadas negativamente, porque? por no explicar y solo colocar codigo, una edicion, y voila, votos positivos, pero no por responder una pregunta de baja calidad

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76142/discussion-between-hector-manuel-martinez-duran-and-ruslan-lopez-carro).

Comment: @HéctorManuelMartinezDurán Ayúdanos a conservar la calidad de la información en el sitio, contestando preguntas que estén basadas en lo definido en el  [help], específicamente [ask]. Revisar [answer].